# GET request on Kotlin Android doesn't resolve url

Tags: android, kotlin, request, get, okhttp

I try to get response from the api of the website https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/city?name=Moscow with OkHTTP and get this error:
Message: Unable to resolve host "api.api-ninjas.com": No address associated with hostname

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val url = "https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/city?name=$cityName"
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .addHeader("X-Api-Key", apiKey)
    .build()
Log.d("CityName", cityName)
var response__ : Response
var latitude = 0
var longitude = 0
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Message: ${e.message}")
            Log.d("FAIL", "")
            // Handle error
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.code.toString())
            Log.d("RESPONSE_HEADERS", response.headers.toString())
            val responseBodyString = response.body?.string()
            if (responseBodyString != null) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE_BODY", responseBodyString)
            }
            response__ = response
            latitude =
                getNextWordAfterTriggerWord(response.body?.byteStream(), "latitude")?.toIntOrNull()
                        ?: 0
            longitude =
                getNextWordAfterTriggerWord(response.body?.byteStream(), "longitude")?.toIntOrNull()
                        ?: 0
        }
})
```

I've already tried using an app called Postman to check if the response will be OK. The response is OK, indeed, but on kotlin it doesn't work and sends this error in the logcat. The API key is correct, because in the app Postman I used an exact API key as in my code.
I think it might be a network problem, because I've got it working one time on the other network, but it doesn;t work anymore

Comment: it's solely about FQDN resolving. The domain is resolvable for me. Not sure how you test that to face the problem though

Comment: I was just reading about why the response might fail. and where was this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/980367/post-requests-from-mobile-network-hotspot-or-not-always-fail), where person was experiencing simmilar problem, but I didn't get how he made a routing rule for ::/0. So I'm clueless, how can I make my requests work with public network, considering that requests from some requests checking app(Postman) doesn't fail at all